# Error when registering JNDI name for Queue by command line in Glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm using Glassfish 4.1.1 and run the following command to register Queue destination JNDI name:

asadmin create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Queue --property Name=myQueue jms/myQueue

But I get the error:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.reader.ProgressStatusDTOJsonProprietaryReader.<clinit>(ProgressStatusDTOJsonProprietaryReader.java:57)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.reader.ProprietaryReaderFactory.<clinit>(ProprietaryReaderFactory.java:60)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain$2.run(AdminMain.java:272)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 4 more
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.reader.ProprietaryReaderFactory
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteRestAdminCommand$1.useConnection(RemoteRestAdminCommand.java:849)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteRestAdminCommand.doHttpCommand(RemoteRestAdminCommand.java:1129)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteRestAdminCommand.doHttpCommand(RemoteRestAdminCommand.java:990)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteRestAdminCommand.executeRemoteCommand(RemoteRestAdminCommand.java:744)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteRestAdminCommand.executeCommand(RemoteRestAdminCommand.java:559)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.remote.RemoteCLICommand.executeCommand(RemoteCLICommand.java:799)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:322)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.remote.RemoteCLICommand.execute(RemoteCLICommand.java:612)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:366)
            at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:300)
            at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)
```

Please help me to resolve the error?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.